# What is this error in build adroid and build app bundle in unity 2017.4.17?

Tags: unity-game-engine, build.gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlgxc.png)[image]

I get some Error when build android in Unity 2017.4.17

I have not problem with unity 5.3.4p3 but google play do not accept my games and it wants x64 so I change to unity 2017.4.17 and in gradle and clicked on build app  bundle (google play )  but I have error

** I Installed some unity version on  pc: unity 5.3.4p3 ,unity 5.4.0.3,unity 2017.4.17,unity 2018.2.18 ,unity 2018.2.15, unity2017.4.28, unity 2017.4.29 , unity 2019.1.2 , unity 2019.1.5 but it does not work them ...Help me please ...help me

I attached errors
this error is

> gradle build failed see the console for details

[image]

I had this error in unity 2019.1.5 too

please help me

I am 30 days in this errors and can not cross it
thanks

I wrote errors in below:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
>   C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe -classpath "F:\files\pc\Video\artoon\program files\UnitySetup64-2017.4.17f1\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradleOut'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)


Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0020e] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:181 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:88 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O2q7.png)

This is mainTemplate file in UnitySetup64-2017.4.17f1>Unity>Editor>Data>PlaybackEngines>AndroidPlayer>Tools>GradleTemplates:

````
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
**DEPS**}

android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        applicationId '**APPLICATIONID**'
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'**STREAMING_ASSETS**
    }

**SIGN**
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_DEBUG**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_DEBUG**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_RELEASE**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_RELEASE**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
            **SIGNCONFIG**
        }
    }
**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}


**SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**```
````

Comment: Go to Preferences -> External Tools  and make sure you have set the JDK path correctly

Comment: yes My jdk is version jdk1.8.0_192

Comment: aswer me please, I ask question but any people do not answer me

Comment: Do one thing create a new empty project and build it. And check if the same error occurs or not

Comment: Thanks Praveen Panishetti  ,I didi it , but  It did not work and I have same Errors what do I do?

Comment: Before clicking on build select the export project.and then hit build and check.

Comment: Checking Build App Bundle gives you .abb file where unchecking it give you the .apk file make sure you want what you need. And I have wrote the answer check that out

Comment: It does not matter to me, but when I wanted to be published on Google Store, I asked: optimize and Build App Bundle  And so I clicked on "Build App Bundle " and I made ".abb " If there's any way I can publish it in internal  ad optimize for "x86 and x64 " please tell me

Comment: Then .abb is the correct thing because unity is no longer supporting internal build. So I will update you about this one

Comment: Please take a screenshot of player settings and post it to question

Comment: Go to "C:\Users\<YourUserName>\.gradle" and delete that whole gradle file.unity will regenerate it while building

Comment: Try Reinstalling JDK as well as Unity. Update to the latest stable version of unity

Comment: Ok thanks,which do version Jdk  I install?

Comment: Jdk1.8.0_171 .  some of the people got rid of this error by downgrading there JDK version.

Comment: Hello again , praveen panishetti , I reinstalled Jdk but I have this problem too,I am confusing. what do I do ? why does not  It work?

Comment: Which version of unity you installed now?

Comment: I have many unity versions on PC (e.x : unity2019.1.5,unity 20019.1.2 ,unity2017.4.20) but I worked unity 2017.4.20 and My JDk 1.8.0_192.In this versions  I have not problem when selected "internal" so I have this problem when select "gradle" and check i "Buil APP Bundle",what do I do? can It be for SDK?

Comment: When you build with internal mode and try to upload to Google Play does it give you error ? And upload player settings window screenshot from unity

Comment: If I build with internal mode in google play ,I have blow error for X86 &ARM64 &armv7:
"Unoptimized APK
Warning:
This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices.
Resolution:
Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs."

Comment: Its totally fine then. using bundle will reduce APK size for users while downloading that's the advantage of app bundle if your app size is not big then it would be better to release it as internal build

Comment: Thanks, What does this mean?
I do not need to check "Build App Bundle" and select Gradle  ,Can I use with Internal mode,,How Can I reduce size?what do I do?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to build the app bundle. What is your current apk size ? check this on how to reduce size [Reducing-File-size](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html). And if you solve this error in future don't forget to answer this question

Comment: MY apk file  with Internal mode is 21.2 Mb and it is a empty project but I have This Error too. I can not  use reduce size because my project is empty (with only a scene ) , , google wants me that I use Build App Budle yet , what do Ido ? I'm waiting for publication for one month I CAN NOT YET ,help me please

Comment: Go to preferences -> External tools and take a screenshot of it and upload it

Comment: I uploaded External tools in main post

Comment: Go to F:\files\pc\Video\artoon\program files\UnitySetup64-2017.4.17f1\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\GradleTemplates you will find a mainTemplate.gradle could you open it and copy that content to question

Comment: Give me your mail address If that fine to you so we can chat. this thread is getting longer

Comment: I upload maintemplate in post and my email is : siavashisajjad@gmail.com

Comment: I uploade main template file  so ca it help to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I Solved this just select Minify release `Gradle` in player setting

1. go to player setting
2. scroll down
3. see publishing setting
4. see Minify
5. select release (`Gradle`) and Debug (`Gradle`)
6. Every things will be fine

   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwmKt.png)

Comment: Dear arsalan , I did  it but I have Error also, SO I have some unity version on  pc: unity 5.3.4p3 ,unity 5.4.0.3,unity 2017.4.17,unity 2018.2.18 ,unity 2018.2.15, unity2017.4.28, unity 2017.4.29 , unity 2019.1.2 , unity 2019.1.5 but it does not work them ...Help me please ...help me

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got almost the same errors and some additional errors

> Could not get resource
>   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom'.

This above kind of error is likely caused due to the **non-availablity of the internet** in your pc.

**So How to fix it ?**

Just make sure you are connected to the internet while building your APK. Unity takes care of the other things

Comment: I  always connected to internet so I have Error if I download this file ( 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom'.) where can I copy it inn Pc?

Comment: I don't have any idea about that one ....looks like some other issue.I will update you if I find any alternative solution

Comment: I think if I found specific location for 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom'. file in Pc .it will work so Where do I must copy this file?

Comment: I don't think the problem will go if you do that. There has to be some other ways to do it. I am also trying to figure it out. I will update you. And by the way try turning off windows defender and firewall and try to build. whatever you do edit the question and update it

Comment: Thanks for answer, I  did turn off   windows defender and firewall but it is error also so I am waiting for your update because I do not know what do I do.. thanks